# ACL: How to check, or uncheck options

Tags: c#, .net, permissions, acl, file-permissions

I add group in ACL for my folder, but I can't check/unchek options for it.

```
String account = @"HYPROSTROY\Все сотрудники";
FileSystemRights rights = FileSystemRights.FullControl;
// I have tried and it too:
// FileSystemRights rights = FileSystemRights.Read | FileSystemRights.Write | FileSystemRights.Modify;
AccessControlType controlType = AccessControlType.Allow;
DirectorySecurity security = local_commonDir.Parent.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.Access);
FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType);

security.AddAccessRule(rule);
// local_commonDir - экземпляр DirectoryInfo
local_commonDir.Parent.SetAccessControl(security);
```

Group was added, but all options are unchecked:

[image]

UPD ===
I have try other method:

```
// String account = Path.Combine(Environment.MachineName, "Пользователи");
String account = @"HYPROSTROY\Все сотрудники";
FileSystemRights rights = FileSystemRights.FullControl;                 
AccessControlType controlType = AccessControlType.Allow;                    
DirectorySecurity security = local_commonDir.Parent.GetAccessControl(AccessControlSections.All);
FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(account, rights, controlType);
//security.AddAccessRule(rule);
Boolean result;
security.ModifyAccessRule(AccessControlModification.Add, rule, out result);
local_commonDir.Parent.SetAccessControl(security);
```

But options is unchecked :(

Where is my mistake?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I found solution:

```
WindowsIdentity id = WindowsIdentity.GetCurrent();
var sid = new SecurityIdentifier(WellKnownSidType.AccountDomainUsersSid, id.User.AccountDomainSid);
var security = dir.GetAccessControl();
var rule = new FileSystemAccessRule(sid,
    FileSystemRights.FullControl,
    InheritanceFlags.ContainerInherit | InheritanceFlags.ObjectInherit,
    PropagationFlags.None,
    AccessControlType.Allow);
security.AddAccessRule(rule);
dir.SetAccessControl(security);
```

Answer (score 0):

This works for me:

```
dir = "C:\test";
DirectorySecurity security = Directory.GetAccessControl(dir);
FileSystemAccessRule rule = new FileSystemAccessRule("Account", FileSystemRights.FullControl, AccessControlType.Allow);
security.AddAccessRule(rule);

Directory.SetAccessControl(dir,security);
```

Comment: here is also an example from msdn...http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.io.directoryinfo.setaccesscontrol%28v=vs.90%29.aspx,
but I saw in this article http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/t1h6d4k4%28v=vs.90%29.aspx the following: Calling this method overload is equivalent to calling the GetAccessControl method overload and specifying the access control sections AccessControlSections.Access | AccessControlSections.Owner | AccessControlSections.Group

Comment: Look my "UPD". I tried use `ModifyAccessRule` too, but it is not helps me.